# AccessDenied - The bucket you access does not belong to you

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I'm starting using Alibaba OSS.

1. I create a bucket.
2. Set permission ACL: Public Read
3. Upload an index.html file
4. When I go to the URL: https://backlinks-seo.oss-us-east-1.aliyuncs.com/ it says:

AccessDenied
The bucket you access does not belong to you.

If I go to https://backlinks-seo.oss-us-east-1.aliyuncs.com/index.html the file gets downloaded.

I don't like to download the file, I would like to see it in the browser.

Please some help!

How could I get access to the root and see the index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure [static website hosting](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31899.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following notice:

> From August 13th, 2018 onwards, when you use an OSS endpoint to access
>   a web file through the Internet, the Content-Disposition:
>   'attachment=filename;' is automatically added to the Response Header,
>   and the web file is downloaded as an attachment.
>
> If you access OSS with a user domain, the Content-Disposition:
>   'attachment=filename;' will not be added to the Response Header. For
>   more information about using the user domain to access OSS, see Bind
>   Custom Domain Names.

Refer: [OSS Web File Response Header Update](https://www.alibabacloud.com/notice/oss0813)

Also, check out the following link for the Tutorial:
[Host a static website using a custom domain name.](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/67323.htm)